# Knockout list not updating with model update

Tags: knockout.js

data model:

```
var people = [
   {
    personName: {
      first: "Fred",
      last: "Flintstone"
    },
    phones: [{
      use: "home",
      phoneNumber: "555-555-1212"
    }],
    emails: [{
      use: "work",
      emailAddress: "fred@example.com"
    }]
  },

   {
    personName: {
      first: "Barney",
      last: "Rubble"
    },
    phones: [{
      use: "home",
      phoneNumber: "555-444-2323"
    }],
    emails: [{
      use: "work",
      emailAddress: "barney@example.com"
    }]
  }
];
```

Knockout:

```
var ContactModel = function(contact) {
    var self = this;

    self.updateModel = function(newcontact) {
        self.personName(newcontact.personName);
        self.emails(newcontact.emails);
        self.phones(newcontact.phones);
    };

    self.personName = ko.observable(contact.personName);
    self.emails = ko.observableArray(contact.emails);
    self.phones = ko.observableArray(contact.phones);

    self.addPhone = function(contact) {
        contact.phones.push({
            use: "",
            phoneNumber: ""
        });
    };

    self.removePhone = function(phone) {
        self.phones.remove(phone);
    };

    self.addEmail = function(contact) {
        contact.emails.push({
            use: "",
            emailAddress: ""
        });
    };

    self.removeEmail = function(email) {
        self.emails.remove(email);
    };
};

var PeopleModel = function(people) {
    var self = this;
    self.contacts = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(people, function(contact) {
        return new ContactModel(contact);
    }));

}
```

DOM:

```
<table id="contactPanelContent">
    // single form edit here, works fine, console shows updated people
</table>

<table id="contactList">
  <tbody>
    <!-- ko foreach: contacts -->
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: $index"></td>
      <!-- ko with: personName -->
      <td data-bind="text: first"></td> 
      <td data-bind="text: last"></td>
      <!-- /ko -->
      <td>
      <!-- ko foreach: phones -->
        <div data-bind="text: phoneNumber"></div>
      <!-- /ko -->
      </td>
      <td>
      <!-- ko foreach: emails -->
        <div data-bind="text: emailAddress"></div>
      <!-- /ko -->
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
bound = new ContactModel(newPerson);
contacts = new PeopleModel(people);
ko.applyBindings(bound, document.getElementById("contactPanelContent"));
ko.applyBindings(contacts, document.getElementById("contactList"));
```

The contact form works fine.  The console shows people with new values.  The form is given a single person from people and the edits reflect in people.  people is also used in #contactList as shown above.  The list renders only once and does not reflect the changes to people.

see: http://plnkr.co/edit/SbIDkG

Comment: I'm not sure as to what your issue is. You write "[...] and the edits reflect in people" and later "[...] and does not reflect the changes to people." Regarding your plnkr, you have bound click events of buttons using jquery instead of databinding them using knockout. In general, I'd suggest using knockout instead of jquery for this, if you want to go the MVVM approach. Also, in the click event listener, you're updating the `bound` object (with an object retrieved from `people`, not from `contacts`), but I couldn't see that you're ever updating the model in the `contacts` list again.

Comment: people is the model.  It is used in the PeopleMode which is the view model.  One item from the people model is updated to the ContactModel, which is the view model for a single contact.  The single contact is edited and the model(people) reflects the change.  Since the view model(PeopleModel) is bound to the model(people) I would expect the binding to update the contact list, it does not.

Comment: My intentions is to bind the edits to the contacts in the list, that is the next step.  There is no jQuery, the pojo events would be bound to the list if I could get it working, I am going one step at a time so yes the intention is to edit a contact by binding to the list.  How the model changes should be irrelevant, if bound to a view model, the dom should reflect the changes.

Comment: I have updated your plnkr to edit a copy of the edited contact and then update the edited contact once the Save-button is pressed, which you can find at http://plnkr.co/edit/PnfiMtT4jNqKoePvwd5E?p=preview. However, the current implementation creates a new contact if it can't match it with a current contact (matching based on name equality). It would be easy to edit it to match either using an ID or using the index of the item under edit.

Comment: Be aware, however, that you have several properties which are observables but have properties which in turn are not observable. Changes to these properties would not be reflected on the DOM, unless the 'parent' observable changes. E.g. in a case of a property `self.name = ko.observable({first: 'abc'});` the DOM would be updated if the code `self.name({first: '123'});` is executed, but not if the code `self.name().first = 123;` is executed. Binding to the `first` property would be equivalent to the latter. Bindings to plain properties are one way bindings, bindings to observables are two way.

Comment: Thanks robert, I have to look through it and see why the add/delete of phone/email does not work on the contact form.  Maybe a hybrid of the two approaches.

Comment: Missed that one. Plnkr updated to make sure that adding and removing phone and e-mail addresses work seemingly correctly.